# What is the simplest way to write a bash script to accept arguments and input from all possible direction (similar to sort -k1 -r)?

Tags: bash, stdin, command-line-arguments

I want to write a bash script that can handle arguments and input similar to many built-in bash command. For example, like sort, it can handle

```
sort -k 1 -r input.txt
sort input.txt -k 1 -r
cat input.txt | sort -k 1 -r
sort -k 1 -r < input.txt
sort -k 1 -r <(cat input.txt)
```

I want my script to be able to handle arguments and input in the similar way

```
myscript.sh -i 3 -b 4 input.txt
myscript.sh input.txt -i 3 -b 4
cat input.txt | myscript.sh -i 3 -b 4
myscript.sh -i 3 -b 4 < input.txt
myscript.sh -i 3 -b 4 <(cat input.txt)
```

so far I only used some features from "read" and "getopts" and think that it's may be buggy if I try to do that on my own.

To make me state my question more clearly, let the content of input.text be

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

and I want to use value from argument i and b to do something but I'll just print it out in this example. The sample output that I want is

```
i : 3
b : 4
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

What is the best way to write a code to handle my above sample commands to give out this output?

Below is the code that got from the sandwich idea of @chepner, which is the best one so far.

```
#!/bin/bash -l
die () {
    echo >&2 "[exception] $@"
    exit 1
}

#parse param
while getopts "i:b:" OPTION; do
  case "$OPTION" in
    i)
      i="$OPTARG"
      ;;
    b)
      b="$OPTARG"
      ;;
    *)
      die "unrecognized option"
      ;;
  esac
done

if [ -e tmpfile ] 
then 
    rm tmpfile 
fi

shift $(($OPTIND - 1))
echo "i : "$i
echo "b : "$b
cat $1 > tmpfile

if read -t 0; then
    cat >> tmpfile
fi

cat tmpfile
```

Comment: what's wrong with getopts? google, there are plenty of examples.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I just don't know how  to use getopts to do above.

Comment: getopts is extremely good at parsing arguments but I couldn't find any examples that use getopts to handle "process substitution" and "pipeline" properly.

Comment: Having the input file name before the options is not usually supported. I don't think `sort` allows that, either. The other cases you list are all trivial with any option processing library, including one you roll yourself with `while` and `case`. (By the by, `sort` is not a builtin, in any shell I have seen.)

Comment: Process substitutions and pipelines are handled by the shell, it is all standard input by the time your program starts.

Comment: @tripleee It maybe my mistake about that "build-in". I tried to imagine how uses can use my script so the above is the way that I used "my common" commands. And it is possible to use file name before options in, at least, "sort" and "wc" so I used it as the example here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Executive summary:** you can use `read -t 0` to test if there is any input available on standard input. It will exit with status 0 data is immediately available on standard input (via a pipe or a redirected file), and 1 if not (e.g., still connected to the keyboard). You can then branch in your script based on whether or not you need to read from standard input.

```
if read -t 0; then
    # Do one thing
else
    # Do something else
fi
```

---

The tricky part for me was writing the script so that it does not block reading standard input if you don't pipe anything to it.

This seems to work; improvements welcome. First, consume everything on standard input; then process files given as arguments.

```
# The first call to read only succeeds when there is input
# available on standard input. It does not actually consume
# a line, though.
if read -t 0; then
    # Read standard input normally
    while read line; do
        echo $line
    done
fi

# I'll assume you populate an array called input files
# while processing your arguments
for file in "${inputfiles[@]"; do 
    cat $file
done
```

Here's a pointless wrapper around `sort` just do demonstrate another way of combining standard input with other input files:

```
if read -t 0; then
    cat | sort fileA fileB
else
    sort fileA file B
fi
```

A slightly more useful command might be `sandwich`, which outputs its standard input (if any) between two files given on the command line.

```
#!/bin/bash

cat "$1"    # Output the first file
read -t 0 && cat # Pass through the standard input, if there is any
cat "$2"    # Output the second file

# cat "$1" - "$2" is almost the same, but requires standard input.
```

Some calls to `sandwich` could be

```
$ sandwich header.txt footer.txt
$ sandwich header.txt footer.txt < body.txt
$ cat chapter1.txt chapter2.txt | sandwich <(echo "My header") <(echo "My footer")
```

This doesn't quite work, so there's room for improvement...

```
$ cat - | sandwich header.txt footer.txt
```

Comment: Can your code handle "process substitution" as "wc -l <(cat input)" do?

Comment: Yes. Process substitution appears to your script as a normal file name: `echo <(echo foo)`. No special handling required; `command1 <(command2)` is a kind of shortcut for `command2 > tmpfile; command1 tmpfile`.

Comment: So your suggestion is that I need to process input from pipe and normal command line separately? I hoped that there may be have a set of commands that can wrap these whole stuffs up.

Comment: Well, you don't need to do them separately, but I don't know what you want to do with the input. I'll update with a few more examples.

Comment: Your sandwich idea is the best for me so far. If no one provide a better answer in a few days, I'll accept your answer. From your suggestion, I'll cat/group/redirect all possible input to the temp file and start my work from there. Thx

Comment: I added the code from your idea to my question and upvote you result. Please let me know if I misunderstand anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat input.txt | command
command < input.txt
command <(cat input.txt)
```

These three are identical from the applications viewpoint, the shell does the redirect. The application only has to read stdin.

```
command input.txt
cat input.txt | command
```

These differ only in the file you process, in the first one it's `input.txt`, in the second one it's stdin, for which you can use `-`, most of the unix commands support it.

```
# echo "X" | cat -
X
```

So you set the default: `filename=-`, and if you read the filename option, you overwrite this variable.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I know that concept and my script must be able to handle that concept but I don't know how to do. I did add some explanation to my question. I hope this will make my question more clear.